# Cómo puedo usar inner join y grup by en desarrollo web

Tags: sql

Me gustaría saber como puedo hacer un conteo de campos de una sub tabla llamada por `inner join` ejemplo tabla 1 contiene los `idpacientes` la tabla 2 tiene todos los datos de esos pacientes lo que quiero es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Lo solucione con este código por si les interesa***

```
SELECT c.idpaciente, p.seguro, p.idpaciente, count(*) as total 
from consulta_programada c 
    inner join perfil_paciente p on c.idpaciente = p.idpaciente 
where c.estado='3' 
group by p.seguro"
```

Comment: y que probaste? es muy importante demostrar que probaste hasta ahora

Comment: ¿Que has intentado? para poderte ayudar con tu pregunta, es necesario que nos muestres que has realizado.

Comment: lo que no se es como combinar un inner join con un group by segun la segunda tabla

Comment: No respondas la pregunta en la misma pregunta. Agrega una respuesta o elimina la pregunta si no sirve.

Answer (score 0):

No puedo probar ahora mismo pero podría ser algo asi:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS CONTEO,
    TABLA2.SEGURO AS SEGURO
FROM TABLA1
    INNER JOIN TABLA2 ON TABLA1.IDPACIENTE = TABLA2.IDPACIENTE
WHERE TABLA1.ESTADO = 3
GROUP BY TABLA2.SEGURO
```

Tu pregunta me hace entender que piensas que hay una forma "especial" de aplicar un ***group by*** cuando se utiliza ***inner join***, pero como puedes ver, no es así.

Comment: gracias amigo ya pude intentado resolverlo antes por aqui lo que utilice para que me de el resultado esperado!

$seguro="SELECT c.idpaciente, p.seguro, p.idpaciente, count(*) as total from consulta_programada c inner join perfil_paciente p on c.idpaciente = p.idpaciente where c.estado='3' group by p.seguro"